# Java multiple user application

Tags: java, rest, api, user-management

I am currently working on an application with Eclipse RCP4. But that is not the main information but just keep it in mind as background information.

I was told that my question did not quite correspond to the standard of this forum so I would like to adapt it herewith.

What is the best way to manage object creation in a multiple user application in Java? Please keep in mind that every object that should be created needs an absolute unique id inside the database.

What the application architecture looks like:

[image: Structure]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited my question. My thought is that it is better to split up the question in multiple parts. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please mention application type? I believe you're talking about web application. If web application then each thread will be managed by Container. Database integration behavior depends on your design.

Comment: JPA, say with eclipseLink: O/R mapping java / database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ID Best Practices for Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350369/id-best-practices-for-databases)

Comment: If you need to use postgres as a DB you should say so in the title and tags, and read questions about [Postgres unique Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)